# Harrower alignment requirement clarification

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class

For the [Harrower prestige class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/harrower) the alignment requirement is:

> **Alignment**: Must be chaotic, evil, good, or lawful (cannot be true neutral). Most harrowers represent alignment extremes: lawful good, chaotic good, lawful evil, or chaotic evil.

In our campaign, we're playing with a five-by-five alignment system (image below) and so that leads me to wonder, would the ruling be that the requirement for a Harrower is to be *both* chaotic, evil, good, or lawful and cannot be true neutral, or that the requirement is to be an alignment that is not true neutral?

Five-by-five alignment chart (ft. Avatar: The Last Airbender).
[image: courtesy of infjeff on r/TheLastAirbender]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take this class as written. It is about alignment extremists, so requiring at least one axis to be at highest or lowest position is reasonable. So I would require chaotic, evil, good, or lawful and forbid whole inner square. But...

## Be consistent

In your campaign you probably already updated rules for druid, paladin, cleric classes, and for spells with alignment descriptor. Above all else, keep your ruling consistent with changes you already made. If this means social neutral can, she can. If it means she can't, she can't.

Answer (score 1):

> Alignment: Must be chaotic, evil, good, or lawful (cannot be true neutral). Most harrowers represent alignment extremes: lawful good, chaotic good, lawful evil, or chaotic evil.

This means that you must not be true neutral and that it is uncommon but possible to have one neutral alignment component.

---

As the class was not meant to be used with this alignment chart it is not possible to give a RAW answer but as the only hard rule is not to be true neutral one can assume that this should be true with other alignment charts, too. And going by this would mean everything but true neutral is allowed.

Comment: So would that mean playing a social neutral character would fulfill the alignment requirement?

Comment: @Cyberson Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

As covered by the other answers, rules don't give an answer here. One suggestion consistent with the original intent is that the character must be at least two steps removed from true neutral in the expanded chart (diagonal steps are not allowed); this means that, say, lawful neutral character qualifies, as does rebel moral one, but social neutral would not, as it is only one step from the centre.